# Using CSS Modules and 3rd party packages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, css-modules

Here is the relevant part of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: [
                "style-loader?sourceMap",
                "css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works great when I'm writing my own css and using it with my `React` components. However, I recently tried using [React Datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) and it comes with its own css files to import into the component that uses React Datepicker.

How can I modify my `webpack.config.js` file so that the React Datepicker css files that I import DON'T get transformed by CSS Modules with local class names? In order words, **is it possible to configure webpack so that it imports 3rd party styles to the global scope and my own styles to a local scope?**

Also, if I want to write my own custom styles that override the React Datepicker styles, how would I do it so that those styles are in global scope as well?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your setup is `exclude: /node_modules/`. Remove this line from your `css` loader setup, and your `React-datepicker` should work.

If you want to override the default style of a third-party component, you can

1. Find out if the library support it by default, some provides themeing options
2. or, you can always find out the CSS that s generated by the library, then override the rules with your own.

**Edit**:

In the case you have to import css explicitly, you can just create a new loader, like this:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'style!css'
}
```

Comment: The problem with removing `node_modules` is that the imported 3rd party styles will get converted to localized css names. For example, "react-date-picker" becomes "app_component_react_datepicker_12345"

Comment: Does the library require you to import css files specifically? Most of the time you wouldn't need as the styles are handled by the library it self internally. You just have to include it in your webpack loaders.

Comment: For react datepicker, you actually do need to explicitly import the styles into your react components

Comment: I see, then you have create a new loader. See edits.

Comment: I'll try that - would you also happen to know how to import css that is globally scoped while using CSS Modules?

Comment: if the global css involve classes, you can do the same here, exclude them from the CSS module loader, but include them in the normal css loader

Answer (score 1):

Using :global(.classname) you can override the external classnames.

Even 3rd party library css can be override.

```
:global(.classname) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```